# Получить List из объектов с одинаковым значениям переменной из другого List

Tags: c#, list

Имеется список SaveList.
Объект SavedList имеет значения int lvl, string Value и string Date.
Мне нужно получить все объекты из списка, у которых lvl равен 1ому.

Т.е.:
Из данного списка

```
SaveList[0]: lvl = 1, Value = "987", Date = "01.02.2005"
SaveList[1]: lvl = 2, Value = "123", Date = "06.07.2009"
SaveList[2]: lvl = 1, Value = "654", Date = "23.05.2012"
```

Должен получиться такой.

```
NewList[0]: lvl = 1, Value = "987", Date = "01.02.2005"
NewList[1]: lvl = 1, Value = "654", Date = "23.05.2012"
```

Извиняюсь за возможные ошибки в составлении вопроса.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class MyClass
{
    public int lvl;
    public string Value;
    public string Date;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<MyClass> list = new List<MyClass>();

        //заполняем список...

        List<MyClass> filtered = list.Where(item => item.lvl == 1).ToList();
    }
}
```